# How to Filter objects and arrays within Javascript Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have some static data I need to filter through based on a few parameters.

I am having some issues filtering deeper than the first value in the array. I reach the first part okay, but I'm not able to filter any deeper on the nested arrays. Here is what the data set looks like.

```
let data = [
    {
      exposureType: "Outdoor",
      unixTime : [
        1632513660, 1632515460, 1632517260, 1632519060, 1632520860, 1632522660,
        1632524460, 1632526260, 1632528060, 1632529860, 1632531660, 1632533460,
        1632535260, 1632537060, 1632538860, 1632540660, 1632542460, 1632544260,
        1632546060, 1632547860, 1632549660, 1632551460, 1632553260, 1632555060,
        1632556860, 1632558660, 1632560460, 1632562260, 1632564060, 1632565860,
        1632567660, 1632569460, 1632571260, 1632573060, 1632574860, 1632576660,
        1632578460, 1632580260, 1632582060, 1632583860, 1632585660, 1632587460,
        1632589260, 1632591060, 1632592860, 1632594660, 1632596460, 1632598260,
        1632600060, 1632601860, 1632603660, 1632605460, 1632607260, 1632609060,
      ],
      rh : [
        45.52, 46.08, 45.48, 44.91, 45.3, 45.82, 47.76, 48.45, 50.16, 51, 50.98,
        52.8, 52.97, 53.91, 54.05, 54.27, 54.25, 54.27, 54.25, 54.29, 54.31,
        54.18, 54.07, 54.09, 54.01, 53.91, 53.85, 54.18, 53.96, 54.07, 53.99,
        53.39, 53.01, 53.53, 54.05, 54.9, 55.54, 56.2, 57.37, 56.91, 57.34
        52.16, 51.15, 50.62, 50.33, 59.31, 67.55, 58.25, 62.4,
      ],
      airTemp : [
        22.5, 22.39, 22.35, 22.25, 22.23, 22.19, 22.12, 22.02, 21.97, 21.9,
        21.88, 21.87, 21.8, 21.8, 21.7, 21.63, 21.53, 21.42, 21.3, 21.18, 21.06,
        20.94, 20.79, 20.7, 20.57, 20.41, 20.24, 20.19, 20.13, 20.06, 20.06,
        20.06, 20.02, 19.96, 19.93, 19.92, 19.91, 19.91, 19.93, 20, 20.08, 20.2,
        20.32, 20.43, 20.57, 20.68, 20.81, 20.97, 21.08, 21.25, 21.39, 21.53,
        21.64, 21.76, 21.78, 21.8, 21.85, 21.87, 21.9, 21.88, 21.87, 21.78,
        21.76, 21.67, 21.6, 21.52, 21.43, 21.33, 21.23, 21.1, 21.05, 20.95
      ],
    },
    {
      exposureType: "Laboratory",
      unixTime: [
        1632513660, 1632515460, 1632517260, 1632519060, 1632520860, 1632522660,
        1632524460, 1632526260, 1632528060, 1632529860, 1632531660, 1632533460,
        1632535260, 1632537060, 1632538860, 1632540660, 1632542460, 1632544260,
        1632546060, 1632547860, 1632549660, 1632551460, 1632553260, 1632555060,
        1632556860, 1632558660, 1632560460, 1632562260, 1632564060, 1632565860,
        1632567660, 1632569460, 1632571260, 1632573060, 1632574860, 1632576660,
        1632578460, 1632580260, 1632582060, 1632583860, 1632585660, 1632587460,
        1632589260, 1632591060, 1632592860, 1632594660, 1632596460, 1632598260,
        1632600060, 1632601860, 1632603660, 1632605460, 1632607260, 1632609060,
        1632610860, 1632612660, 1632614460, 1632616260, 1632618060, 1632619860,
      ],
      rh: [
        45.52, 46.08, 45.48, 44.91, 45.3, 45.82, 47.76, 48.45, 50.16, 51, 50.98,
        52.8, 52.97, 53.91, 54.05, 54.27, 54.25, 54.27, 54.25, 54.29, 54.31,
        54.18, 54.07, 54.09, 54.01, 53.91, 53.85, 54.18, 53.96, 54.07, 53.99,
        53.39, 53.01, 53.53, 54.05, 54.9, 55.54, 56.2, 57.37, 56.91, 57.34,
        57.33, 56.26, 55.45, 54.81, 54.42, 53.81, 53.75, 53.48, 53.44, 53.75,
        53.73, 53.57, 52.99, 53.93, 54.14, 54.71, 54.94, 55.8, 56.24, 55.38,
        56.65, 55.79, 55.21, 55.02, 54.51, 54.18, 53.92, 53.75, 53.58, 53.56,
        53.41, 53.63, 53.63, 53.48, 53.89, 53.98, 53.87, 53.59, 53.09, 53.03,
      ],
      airTemp: [
        22.5, 22.39, 22.35, 22.25, 22.23, 22.19, 22.12, 22.02, 21.97, 21.9,
        21.88, 21.87, 21.8, 21.8, 21.7, 21.63, 21.53, 21.42, 21.3, 21.18, 21.06,
        20.94, 20.79, 20.7, 20.57, 20.41, 20.24, 20.19, 20.13, 20.06, 20.06,
        20.06, 20.02, 19.96, 19.93, 19.92, 19.91, 19.91, 19.93, 20, 20.08, 20.2,
        20.32, 20.43, 20.57, 20.68, 20.81, 20.97, 21.08, 21.25, 21.39, 21.53,
        21.64, 21.76, 21.78, 21.8, 21.85, 21.87, 21.9, 21.88, 21.87, 21.78,
      ],
    },
  ];
```

I pass in four parameters that look like this.

```
sensorData("Outdoor", "airTemp", 20, 22)
```

I then want to filter on the first elemement like this.

```
  let filterdArray = data.filter((val) => val.exposureType === exposureType );
```

This part seems to work. It will bring back the object labeled "Outdoor" in this instance.
However, nothing past this point works.

I then aim to find the "airTemp" array and filter on it with min and max values. The 20 and 22 parameter values. it doesn't work though. I still brings back all arrays and values in that object.

I've tried things like this.

```
let filterdArray = data.filter((val) => val.exposureType === exposureType && val.airTemp > min && val.airTemp < max);



filterdArray.map((element) => {
    return {...element, SubElements: element.SubElements.filter((subElement) => subElement.airTemp)}
  })
```

Neither of which work.

I'm new to filtering in Javascript, so I'm not sure the best way to do this. Is there a way to accomplish what I've laid out ?

Grateful for your help.

Comment: A question. When you say you need to filter on `airtemp` what do you expect it to do? Do you expect it to return filtered `airtemp` array or you want to check if value exists in this range?

Comment: @Rajesh I expect it to return filtered airTemp. So filter airTemp between the min and max values I send to it

Comment: You want to read the `exposureType` whose value is "Outdoor" and then filter that `exposureType`'s `airtemp` to be between a given min and max value... is that correct ? And what is the structure of the output you are expecting ?

Comment: @NalinRanjan Yes, that is exactly right. I expect the output to be the exposureType string and filtered airTemp data in an array

Comment: @swapmeet_Lou I have added an answer with explanation. Hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***The Function***

```js
function filter_sensor_data_for_within_range(sensorData, exposureType, filterFor, minValue, maxValue) {
    return filter_range(read_exposure_for(read_exposure_type(sensorData)));
    function read_exposure_type(sensorData) {
        if (sensorData && sensorData.length) {
            return sensorData.find(dataEntry => dataEntry.exposureType === exposureType) || {};
        }
        return {};
    }
    function read_exposure_for(exposureData) {
        return { exposureType: exposureData.exposureType, [filterFor]: exposureData[filterFor] || [] };
    }
    function filter_range(exposureDataProperty) {
        return { exposureType: exposureDataProperty.exposureType, [filterFor]: exposureDataProperty[filterFor].filter((temp) => temp >= minValue && temp <= maxValue) };
    }
}
```

---

### ***Illustration***

```js
function filter_sensor_data_for_within_range(sensorData, exposureType, filterFor, minValue, maxValue) {
  return filter_range(read_exposure_for(read_exposure_type(sensorData)));

  function read_exposure_type(sensorData) {
    if (sensorData && sensorData.length) {
      return sensorData.find(dataEntry => dataEntry.exposureType === exposureType) || {};
    }
    return {};
  }

  function read_exposure_for(exposureData) {
    return {
      exposureType: exposureData.exposureType,
      [filterFor]: exposureData[filterFor] || []
    };
  }

  function filter_range(exposureDataProperty) {
    return {
      exposureType: exposureDataProperty.exposureType,
      [filterFor]: exposureDataProperty[filterFor].filter((temp) => temp >= minValue && temp <= maxValue)
    };
  }
}
const data = [{
    exposureType: "Outdoor",
    unixTime: [
      1632513660, 1632515460, 1632517260, 1632519060, 1632520860, 1632522660,
      1632524460, 1632526260, 1632528060, 1632529860, 1632531660, 1632533460,
      1632535260, 1632537060, 1632538860, 1632540660, 1632542460, 1632544260,
      1632546060, 1632547860, 1632549660, 1632551460, 1632553260, 1632555060,
      1632556860, 1632558660, 1632560460, 1632562260, 1632564060, 1632565860,
      1632567660, 1632569460, 1632571260, 1632573060, 1632574860, 1632576660,
      1632578460, 1632580260, 1632582060, 1632583860, 1632585660, 1632587460,
      1632589260, 1632591060, 1632592860, 1632594660, 1632596460, 1632598260,
      1632600060, 1632601860, 1632603660, 1632605460, 1632607260, 1632609060,
    ],
    rh: [
      45.52, 46.08, 45.48, 44.91, 45.3, 45.82, 47.76, 48.45, 50.16, 51, 50.98,
      52.8, 52.97, 53.91, 54.05, 54.27, 54.25, 54.27, 54.25, 54.29, 54.31,
      54.18, 54.07, 54.09, 54.01, 53.91, 53.85, 54.18, 53.96, 54.07, 53.99,
      53.39, 53.01, 53.53, 54.05, 54.9, 55.54, 56.2, 57.37, 56.91, 57.34,
      52.16, 51.15, 50.62, 50.33, 59.31, 67.55, 58.25, 62.4,
    ],
    airTemp: [
      22.5, 22.39, 22.35, 22.25, 22.23, 22.19, 22.12, 22.02, 21.97, 21.9,
      21.88, 21.87, 21.8, 21.8, 21.7, 21.63, 21.53, 21.42, 21.3, 21.18, 21.06,
      20.94, 20.79, 20.7, 20.57, 20.41, 20.24, 20.19, 20.13, 20.06, 20.06,
      20.06, 20.02, 19.96, 19.93, 19.92, 19.91, 19.91, 19.93, 20, 20.08, 20.2,
      20.32, 20.43, 20.57, 20.68, 20.81, 20.97, 21.08, 21.25, 21.39, 21.53,
      21.64, 21.76, 21.78, 21.8, 21.85, 21.87, 21.9, 21.88, 21.87, 21.78,
      21.76, 21.67, 21.6, 21.52, 21.43, 21.33, 21.23, 21.1, 21.05, 20.95
    ],
  },
  {
    exposureType: "Laboratory",
    unixTime: [
      1632513660, 1632515460, 1632517260, 1632519060, 1632520860, 1632522660,
      1632524460, 1632526260, 1632528060, 1632529860, 1632531660, 1632533460,
      1632535260, 1632537060, 1632538860, 1632540660, 1632542460, 1632544260,
      1632546060, 1632547860, 1632549660, 1632551460, 1632553260, 1632555060,
      1632556860, 1632558660, 1632560460, 1632562260, 1632564060, 1632565860,
      1632567660, 1632569460, 1632571260, 1632573060, 1632574860, 1632576660,
      1632578460, 1632580260, 1632582060, 1632583860, 1632585660, 1632587460,
      1632589260, 1632591060, 1632592860, 1632594660, 1632596460, 1632598260,
      1632600060, 1632601860, 1632603660, 1632605460, 1632607260, 1632609060,
      1632610860, 1632612660, 1632614460, 1632616260, 1632618060, 1632619860,
    ],
    rh: [
      45.52, 46.08, 45.48, 44.91, 45.3, 45.82, 47.76, 48.45, 50.16, 51, 50.98,
      52.8, 52.97, 53.91, 54.05, 54.27, 54.25, 54.27, 54.25, 54.29, 54.31,
      54.18, 54.07, 54.09, 54.01, 53.91, 53.85, 54.18, 53.96, 54.07, 53.99,
      53.39, 53.01, 53.53, 54.05, 54.9, 55.54, 56.2, 57.37, 56.91, 57.34,
      57.33, 56.26, 55.45, 54.81, 54.42, 53.81, 53.75, 53.48, 53.44, 53.75,
      53.73, 53.57, 52.99, 53.93, 54.14, 54.71, 54.94, 55.8, 56.24, 55.38,
      56.65, 55.79, 55.21, 55.02, 54.51, 54.18, 53.92, 53.75, 53.58, 53.56,
      53.41, 53.63, 53.63, 53.48, 53.89, 53.98, 53.87, 53.59, 53.09, 53.03,
    ],
    airTemp: [
      22.5, 22.39, 22.35, 22.25, 22.23, 22.19, 22.12, 22.02, 21.97, 21.9,
      21.88, 21.87, 21.8, 21.8, 21.7, 21.63, 21.53, 21.42, 21.3, 21.18, 21.06,
      20.94, 20.79, 20.7, 20.57, 20.41, 20.24, 20.19, 20.13, 20.06, 20.06,
      20.06, 20.02, 19.96, 19.93, 19.92, 19.91, 19.91, 19.93, 20, 20.08, 20.2,
      20.32, 20.43, 20.57, 20.68, 20.81, 20.97, 21.08, 21.25, 21.39, 21.53,
      21.64, 21.76, 21.78, 21.8, 21.85, 21.87, 21.9, 21.88, 21.87, 21.78,
    ],
  },
];
console.log(filter_sensor_data_for_within_range(data, "Outdoor", "airTemp", 20, 22));
```

---

***`WYSIWYG`*** => ***`WHAT YOU SHOW IS WHAT YOU GET`***

Comment: grateful for the help. The others partially worked, as they brought back the filtered array, but they brought everything else back as well. Your solution only returned the airTemp. Which is what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First filter, then map and filter the inner property values through the map.

```
const sensorData = (exposureType, property, min, max) => {
  return data.filter((val) => val.exposureType === exposureType).map(v => {
    if (v.hasOwnProperty(property)) v[property] = v[property].filter(f => f >= min && f <= max);
    return v
  })
}
sensorData("Outdoor", "airTemp", 20, 22)
```

```js
let data = [{
    exposureType: "Outdoor",
    unixTime: [
      1632513660, 1632515460, 1632517260, 1632519060, 1632520860, 1632522660,
      1632524460, 1632526260, 1632528060, 1632529860, 1632531660, 1632533460,
      1632535260, 1632537060, 1632538860, 1632540660, 1632542460, 1632544260,
      1632546060, 1632547860, 1632549660, 1632551460, 1632553260, 1632555060,
      1632556860, 1632558660, 1632560460, 1632562260, 1632564060, 1632565860,
      1632567660, 1632569460, 1632571260, 1632573060, 1632574860, 1632576660,
      1632578460, 1632580260, 1632582060, 1632583860, 1632585660, 1632587460,
      1632589260, 1632591060, 1632592860, 1632594660, 1632596460, 1632598260,
      1632600060, 1632601860, 1632603660, 1632605460, 1632607260, 1632609060
    ],
    rh: [
      45.52, 46.08, 45.48, 44.91, 45.3, 45.82, 47.76, 48.45, 50.16, 51, 50.98,
      52.8, 52.97, 53.91, 54.05, 54.27, 54.25, 54.27, 54.25, 54.29, 54.31,
      54.18, 54.07, 54.09, 54.01, 53.91, 53.85, 54.18, 53.96, 54.07, 53.99,
      53.39, 53.01, 53.53, 54.05, 54.9, 55.54, 56.2, 57.37, 56.91, 57.34,
      52.16, 51.15, 50.62, 50.33, 59.31, 67.55, 58.25, 62.4
    ],
    airTemp: [
      22.5, 22.39, 22.35, 22.25, 22.23, 22.19, 22.12, 22.02, 21.97, 21.9,
      21.88, 21.87, 21.8, 21.8, 21.7, 21.63, 21.53, 21.42, 21.3, 21.18, 21.06,
      20.94, 20.79, 20.7, 20.57, 20.41, 20.24, 20.19, 20.13, 20.06, 20.06,
      20.06, 20.02, 19.96, 19.93, 19.92, 19.91, 19.91, 19.93, 20, 20.08, 20.2,
      20.32, 20.43, 20.57, 20.68, 20.81, 20.97, 21.08, 21.25, 21.39, 21.53,
      21.64, 21.76, 21.78, 21.8, 21.85, 21.87, 21.9, 21.88, 21.87, 21.78,
      21.76, 21.67, 21.6, 21.52, 21.43, 21.33, 21.23, 21.1, 21.05, 20.95
    ],
  },
  {
    exposureType: "Laboratory",
    unixTime: [
      1632513660, 1632515460, 1632517260, 1632519060, 1632520860, 1632522660,
      1632524460, 1632526260, 1632528060, 1632529860, 1632531660, 1632533460,
      1632535260, 1632537060, 1632538860, 1632540660, 1632542460, 1632544260,
      1632546060, 1632547860, 1632549660, 1632551460, 1632553260, 1632555060,
      1632556860, 1632558660, 1632560460, 1632562260, 1632564060, 1632565860,
      1632567660, 1632569460, 1632571260, 1632573060, 1632574860, 1632576660,
      1632578460, 1632580260, 1632582060, 1632583860, 1632585660, 1632587460,
      1632589260, 1632591060, 1632592860, 1632594660, 1632596460, 1632598260,
      1632600060, 1632601860, 1632603660, 1632605460, 1632607260, 1632609060,
      1632610860, 1632612660, 1632614460, 1632616260, 1632618060, 1632619860
    ],
    rh: [
      45.52, 46.08, 45.48, 44.91, 45.3, 45.82, 47.76, 48.45, 50.16, 51, 50.98,
      52.8, 52.97, 53.91, 54.05, 54.27, 54.25, 54.27, 54.25, 54.29, 54.31,
      54.18, 54.07, 54.09, 54.01, 53.91, 53.85, 54.18, 53.96, 54.07, 53.99,
      53.39, 53.01, 53.53, 54.05, 54.9, 55.54, 56.2, 57.37, 56.91, 57.34,
      57.33, 56.26, 55.45, 54.81, 54.42, 53.81, 53.75, 53.48, 53.44, 53.75,
      53.73, 53.57, 52.99, 53.93, 54.14, 54.71, 54.94, 55.8, 56.24, 55.38,
      56.65, 55.79, 55.21, 55.02, 54.51, 54.18, 53.92, 53.75, 53.58, 53.56,
      53.41, 53.63, 53.63, 53.48, 53.89, 53.98, 53.87, 53.59, 53.09, 53.03
    ],
    airTemp: [
      22.5, 22.39, 22.35, 22.25, 22.23, 22.19, 22.12, 22.02, 21.97, 21.9,
      21.88, 21.87, 21.8, 21.8, 21.7, 21.63, 21.53, 21.42, 21.3, 21.18, 21.06,
      20.94, 20.79, 20.7, 20.57, 20.41, 20.24, 20.19, 20.13, 20.06, 20.06,
      20.06, 20.02, 19.96, 19.93, 19.92, 19.91, 19.91, 19.93, 20, 20.08, 20.2,
      20.32, 20.43, 20.57, 20.68, 20.81, 20.97, 21.08, 21.25, 21.39, 21.53,
      21.64, 21.76, 21.78, 21.8, 21.85, 21.87, 21.9, 21.88, 21.87, 21.78
    ],
  },
];

const sensorData = (exposureType, property, min, max) => {
  return data.filter((val) => val.exposureType === exposureType).map(v => {
    if (v.hasOwnProperty(property)) v[property] = v[property].filter(f => f >= min && f <= max);
    return v
  })
}

 

console.log(sensorData("Outdoor", "airTemp", 20, 22))
```

Comment: Minor suggestion, if you want to add check, try using `Array.isArray` instead as its safer.

Answer (score 0):

#### Issue with your approach:

```
val.exposureType === exposureType && val.airTemp > min && val.airTemp < max
```

This is an expression in filter and will be evaluated as false as `val.airTemp` is an array. So you are comparing number with an array.

#### Solution:

You will have to imploy 2 step process:

1. Filter out objects based on exposure type
2. Loop on filtered objects and filter out `airTemp`

- For this, you will have to use `.map` as you need a mutated value for all filtered objects.
- Filter `airTemp` and save it in a variable
- Use this value to override property in object and return this object

#### [Example](https://jsfiddle.net/dg1x0p62/)

```js
function sensorData(exposureType, property, minVal, maxVal) {
  const result = data
    .filter((item) => item.exposureType === exposureType)
    .map((item) => {
      const value = item[property] &&
        item[property].filter((val) => val >= minVal && val < maxVal)
      return { ...item,
        [property]: value
      }
    })
  return result
}
```

Or if you want to do it in 1 loop:

```js
function sensorData(exposureType, property, minVal, maxVal) {
  return data.reduce((acc, item) => {
    if (item.exposureType === exposureType) {
      const filterVal = item[property] &&
        item[property].filter((val) => minVal <= val && val < maxVal)
      acc.push({
        ...item,
        [property]: filterVal
      })
    }
    return acc
  }, [])
}
```